# python: changing list value in sub-routine

Tags: python, list, subroutine, function-parameter

I have a simple example.
The function ***test_list_change*** should change the list passed to it as a parameter.
And inside this function there is a call to sub-routine ***test_list_change_2*** which should change the same list.

The problem is, that the result list doesn't contain changes made by the ***test_list_change_2*** subroutine

Why it could be?

Here is the example:

```
def test_list_change(lst):
    if len(lst) < 3:
        lst.append("the last one")
        test_list_change_2(lst)

def test_list_change_2(lst):
    lst = ["the very last one"]

string_list = ["first", "another one"]
test_list_change(string_list)
print (string_list)
```

The output:

> ['first', 'another one', 'the last one']

Comment: just returning  `return ["the very last one"] ` is the same as what you are trying to do in your  function, I don't think your code is going to do what you expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually change the original `list/object`:

```
def test_list_change(lst):
    if len(lst) < 3:
        lst.append("the last one")
        test_list_change_2(lst)

def test_list_change_2(lst):
    lst[:] = ["the very last one"] # changes original list object

string_list = ["first", "another one"]
test_list_change(string_list)
print (string_list)
['the very last one']
```

If you want to change around the elements:

```
def test_list_change_2(lst):
    lst[:-1] = ["the very last one"]
    lst[:] = lst[::-1]

string_list = ["first", "another one"]
test_list_change(string_list)
print (string_list)
['the last one', 'the very last one']
```

You can manipulate the list whatever way you like but you need to actually refer to the original list object, reassigning a name won't change the lst it will just assign that name to another object.

Comment: thanks, that's what I needed - to understand how to change original list.

Answer (score 1):

You probably got confused how things work in python with "passing by reference" and thought that since it is passed by reference, so the original list should be updated to ["the very last one"].

It works in the following manner:

1) before test_list_change is called, there is a name "string_list" and python creates a object ["first", "another one"] which is assigned to string_list

2) now in test_list_change, a new name "lst" is assigned with ["first", "another one"]. So now both names are assigned with the same object. It is then appended and changed to ['first', 'another one', 'the last one'], pointed by both string_list and lst

3) In test_list_change_2, before you do the assignment, there exist another local lst name which points to ["first", "another one", 'ths last one']. Then python creates another object ['the vary last one'] and replaces the value of the local lst variable.

4) string_list still points to ['first', 'another one', 'the last one']

So another way to put it, variables are just names passed around and objects are managed 'by reference'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `["the very last one"]` in `test_list_change_2` :

```
def test_list_change_2():
    return ["the very last one"]
```

and assign the result of function to `lst` in first function :

```
def test_list_change(lst):
    if len(lst) < 3:
        lst.append("the last one")
        lst= test_list_change_2()
```

Note that actually you dont need a function here !!! you can do this assignment in the firs function .

Comment: the lst was assigned new value, isn't it? _lst= ["the very last one"]_

Comment: No, the list wasn't assigned a new value.  The name `lst` had a new list object assigned to it.  The object passed in and given the name `lst` is unaffected.

Comment: @Vcitor assignment is a change but  for such tasks you dont need do more work with function as it waste the memory !

Comment: If the only change you make to the code is adding `return lst` to `test_list_change_2`, the output will still be what the OP has now, because the returned value isn't assigned to anything in `test_list_change`, and even if you did `lst = test_list_change_2(lst)`, the change wouldn't propagate to `string_lst`.

Comment: @paidhima, and how can I change the original object with the new value, to replace it with list only with one element with value "the very last one"?

Comment: @Vcitor whats your desire out put ?

Comment: @Kasra AD, it's just an example. i have another function which is more complicated and doesn't work as expected. it's quite big that is why I posted a similar example here.

Comment: @Vcitor imean that whats your expected out put for `["first", "another one"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `test_list_change2` procedure is doing `lst = ['the very last one']`.  It's simply assigning a new object to the local name `lst`.  It has no effect whatsoever on the list passed in to that procedure.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  If you want `test_list_change2` to add to `lst`, just append it.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get just "the very last one" to be in the list then:

```
def test_list_change(lst):
    if len(lst) < 3:
        lst.append("the last one")
    lst = test_list_change_2(lst)

def test_list_change_2(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst.pop()
    lst.append("the very last one")


string_list = ["first", "another one"]
test_list_change(string_list)
print (string_list)
```